# EF saving multiple instances of same object

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

Here's the situation. I create 1 object (a product) and then save it through my db context. I then load that product from the database and put them in another object(download) and save that object. EF then creates another db entry for the original product loaded. So now I have two of the same product in the db. Is this working as intended? I thought EF kept track of objects loaded from the database to prevent stuff like this.

Ok here's some random code with one product if you really want it.

```
product product1 = new product{blah blah blah};
context.Products.add(product1);
context.savechanges();

var prod1 = context.Products.Where(x => x.Id == 1).FirstOrDefault();

user = new User { new Download {product = (product)prod1}};
context.Users.add(user);
context.save(user);
```

Comment: Why Does Entity Framework Reinsert Existing Objects into My Database? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
var prod = context.Products.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == 1);
User user = context.Users.Create();
user.Product = prod;
context.Users.Add(user);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Or more easily...

```
User user = context.Users.Create();
user.ProductId = productId;
context.Users.Add(user);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: So basically the problem originates from the fact that the user I create is disconnected from the context?