# Aggregation inserting also creating a new child element with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

If we have an aggregation relationship A to B:

```
A
{
    public virtual B B {get; set; }
}
```

Before we insert A into the database, A.B is retrieved from the database and assign for it. However, after saving A into the new database, instead of referring a foreign key in the database, a new B is created. How can we just insert A and references A.B to an existing B?

Comment: Why Does Entity Framework Reinsert Existing Objects into My Database?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [EF saving multiple instances of same object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19436875/ef-saving-multiple-instances-of-same-object)